Getting Session from Next API routes Using cradentials Login
I am using Next-auth for my authentication, using the credentials login (JWT) and signup (made my own API for it). I want to access my session on API routes but seems like I am not getting it. When I log the session it gives me null on API route.
export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(authConfig);
    console.log("REQUEST", req);

    console.log("SESSION", session);
    if (session?.user?.role !== "admin") {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "You are not authorized" },
        { status: HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized }
      );
    }
    await dbConnect();

    let users = await User.find({});
    return NextResponse.json({ data: users }, { status: HttpStatusCode.NotFound });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: error }, { status: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest });
  }
} 

I am calling the API like this.
const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
    // const token = getToken()?.value;
    // console.log("TOKEN", token);
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/user`);

    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

My auth options includes this:
export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Sign in",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "john.doe@example.com",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "********",
        },
      },

      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          if (!credentials || !credentials.password || !credentials.email) return null;
          await dbConnect();
          // QUERY DATABASE FOR A USER BY EMAIL
          let user: any = await User.findOne({
            email: credentials.email,
          })
            .select("+password")
            .lean();

          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }
          // COMPARE PASSWORD HASH
          const isMatch = await compareHash(credentials.password, user.password);
          if (!isMatch) {
            return null;
          }
          const { password, createdAt, ...otherUserData } = user;
          console.log("USERRR", otherUserData);
          return otherUserData;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt", // SET SESSION STRATEGY TO JWT
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, // USE SECRET KEY FROM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      // IF USER EXISTS, ADD USER INFO TO JWT TOKEN
      user && (token.user = user);
      console.log("Token", token, user);
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      // ADD USER INFO TO SESSION
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

I don't know what I am doing wrong init. If I am doing something wrong kindly guide me to the solution.
